# how to read nested JSON/array data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, next.js, graphql

My data is something like which is in a const translations.

```
{
  "item-0": {
    "_quote-translation": "translation Data",
    "_quote-translation-language": "English",
    "_quote-translation-author-name": "",
    "_quote-translation-source": ""
  },
  "item-1": {
    "_quote-translation": "translation Data",
    "_quote-translation-language": "English",
    "_quote-translation-author-name": "",
    "_quote-translation-source": ""
  },
  "item-2": {
    "_quote-translation": "translation Data",
    "_quote-translation-language": "English",
    "_quote-translation-author-name": "",
    "_quote-translation-source": ""
  },
  "item-3": {
    "_quote-translation": "translation Data",
    "_quote-translation-language": "English",
    "_quote-translation-author-name": "",
    "_quote-translation-source": ""
  }
}
```

I want to display all translations and their language by using map function in nextjs. But it is not returning the data.

```
    {translations.map((translation, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h2>name: {translation._quote-translation}</h2>
            <h2>country: {translation._quote-translation-language}</h2>

            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

How can I read the required data in this nested JSON object?

Comment: You are iterating through an Object and not an Array. The `map` method is for the Array data type.

Comment: there's no Array in the data, and there's no such thing as a JSON object - since JSON is by it's nature, simply a **string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve all of the keys within in a object, then iterate over the returned array of keys in React to target the translation item:

```
return (
    <div>
        {/* Equivalent to ["item-0", "item-1", ...].map(...) */}
        { Object.keys(translation).map(itemId => (
            <div key={itemId}>
                <h2>
                    {/* Target the value by using the provided key */}
                    name: {translation[itemId]["_quote-translation"]}
                </h2>
                <h2>
                    country: {translation[itemId]["_quote-translation-language"]}
                </h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Also, it should be worth noting that in JavaScript you cannot target a JSON key using dot syntax (`translation.x-y-z`) if the key contains dashes. You *must* use the bracket syntax (`translation["x-y-z"]`).

If optional chaining becomes a requirement, you can use `translation?.["x-y-z"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    {Object.keys(translations).map((translation, index) => {
    return (
       <div key={index}>
         <h2>name: {translations[`${translation}`]["_quote-translation"]} 
         </h2>
         <h2>country: {translations[`${translation}`]["_quote-translation-language"]}</h2>
         <hr />
       </div>
      )
   }}
```

Basically, we can iterate any Object using `Object.keys(#object).map(...)` or `Object.entries(#Object).map(...)`

Comment: it is returning the name: Nan instead of "translation Data" for all 4 loops.

Comment: This will work Inshallah. Nan is because you have named the keys as String. This is why you are not able to access the value.  Now try this... {Object.keys(translations).map((translation, index) => {
    return (
       <div key={index}>
         <h2>name: {translations[`${translation}`]["_quote-translation"]} 
         </h2>
         <h2>country: {translations[`${translation}`]["_quote-translation-language"]}</h2>
      <hr />
    </div>
    )
}}

Comment: I have edited the answer above. Please, try this now.